# How to get rid of such radicals?

Tags: abstract-algebra, radicals, cubics, nested-radicals

I would like to know if there is any way I can get rid of these cubic radicals bellow (1). I am allowing both complex and real values.

$$ \sqrt[3]{ -\frac{q}{2} + \sqrt{\frac{q^2}{4} + \frac{p^3}{27} } } + \sqrt[3]{ -\frac{q}{2} - \sqrt{\frac{q^2}{4} + \frac{p^3}{27} } } = x + C\,\,\,\, (1)$$

If it were a second order radical, it wouldn't be as harsh as it is for such radicals above. Since we could raise both sides to $2$.

$$\sqrt{\frac{q^2}{4} + \frac{p^3}{27} } = x+C\,\,\,\, (2)$$

I tried to do the same for (1), however the radicals did not vanish. I also tried this:

$$\sqrt[3]{ -\frac{q}{2} + \sqrt{\frac{q^2}{4} + \frac{p^3}{27} } } = x+C-\sqrt[3]{ -\frac{q}{2} - \sqrt{\frac{q^2}{4} + \frac{p^3}{27} } }$$

And then raise to the cube. But no pleasant results.

Comment: The LHS is a root of the polynomial $z^3+pz+q$. Hence, $(x+C)^3+p(x+C)+q=0.$

Comment: Thanks, @YvesDaoust, for your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint :** For
$$A =\sqrt[3]{ -\frac{q}{2} + \sqrt{\frac{q^2}{4} + \frac{p^3}{27} } }$$ your equation can be rewritten as

$$A  - \frac{p}{3A} = x+ C$$

Comment: Oh I see. Then I can turn $A$ into a second order radical. But how did you know that? Any references recommendation would be highly appreciated. Never seen this before. Thanks!

Comment: I "noticed" that multiplying the two radicals of your equation together would make great simplification :)